# How do I calculate the Mean Relative Absolute Error in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

How can I use the Mean Relative absolute error loss function in my neural network instead of the mean square error? This is my current code:

```
class NNBase(nn.Module):

def training_step(self, batch):
    inputs, targets = batch 
    # Generate predictions
    out = self(inputs)          
    # Calcuate loss
    L=nn.MSELoss()
    loss = L(out,targets)#+torch.abs(out.sum()-1)                       
    return loss

def validation_step(self, batch):
    inputs, targets = batch
    # Generate predictions
    out = self(inputs)
    # Calculate loss
    L=nn.MSELoss()
    loss = L(out,targets)#+torch.abs(out.sum()-1)                              
    return {'val_loss': loss.detach()}
    
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
    epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
    return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item()}

def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
    # Print result every 20th epoch
    print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {}".format(epoch+1, result['val_loss']))
```

I would like to ask if there's a Mean Relative Absolute Error loss function defined in Pytorch
I already found a class of it on the PyTorch website (https://pytorch.org/ignite/generated/ignite.contrib.metrics.regression.MeanAbsoluteRelativeError.html ) but I wasn't able to call it by `nn.MeanAbsoluteRelativeError`.

Answer (score 0):

ignite is a separate package altogether. You have to install it separately using `pip install pytorch-ignite`. Once you have the package installed, you can use the `MeanAbsoluteRelativeError` API from `ignite.contrib.metrics.regression`.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. I already installed ignite and ' import ignite ' work without any problem but when i call ' ignite.contrib.metrics.regression.MeanAbsoluteRelativeError() ' i got this error " module 'ignite.contrib' has no attribute 'metrics' "

Comment: you have to import it like this `from ignite.contrib.metrics.regression import MeanAbsoluteRelativeError`  and use `MeanAbsoluteRelativeError()` where ever needed in the code.